# django crontab job does not work

Tags: python, linux, django, cron

I have a very simple django project that consists of one application model called Quote.

The application simply has a cron job that executes every 1 minute to get a random quote from the DB and use notify-send command to show a notification with that quote.

I am using django-crontab to achieve this goal.

The cron.py is very simple as show below

```
from random import randint
from models import Quote
import subprocess, time, os

def notify():
    latestQuote = Quote.objects.all().order_by("-id")[0]
    max_id = latestQuote.id
    quote = Quote.objects.get(pk=randint(1,max_id))
    subprocess.Popen(['notify-send',quote.quote])
    time.sleep(1)
```

And here is the cron settings in the settings module

```
CRONJOBS = [('*/1 * * * *', 'core.cron.notify')]
```

When executing `./manage crontab add`, a cron command is added to my crontab  as following

```
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/python /home/anas/storage/motinder/manage.py crontab run 5ade4dc167538a33802640eeb92219ad # django-cronjobs for motinder
```

If I executed the command from the system crontab, the notification is displayed successfully BUT the cron job does not execute automatically.

## Edit

I changed the code in the cron.py file to send a static notification instead of getting the quote from the DB. Check below

```
from random import randint
from models import Quote
import subprocess, time, os

def notify():
    #latestQuote = Quote.objects.all().order_by("-id")[0]
    #max_id = latestQuote.id
    #quote = Quote.objects.get(pk=randint(1,max_id))
    #subprocess.Popen(['notify-send',quote.quote])
    subprocess.Popen(['notify-send',"TEST"])
    time.sleep(1)
```

Unfortunately the situation is the same.

Comment: You really don't need third party apps to setup a conjob, all these complications can be avoided by simply configuring your notify.py as a CLI and adding it direct to crontab http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/django/5848/django-from-the-command-line#t=201611230712189521958

Comment: appreciating your comment @e4c5 but my point here is to use Django ORM to ease querying on the DB. One more note, I tried the same approach using a simple python script that do nothing except execute the `notify-send` command but the situation remains the same.

Comment: And that's exactly what I am suggesting too. without all this hocus pocus of popen.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to had the correct Shebang line on top of your python script and make your file executable with `chmod +x`?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from random import randint
from models import Quote
import subprocess, time, os

def notify():
    latestQuote = Quote.objects.all().order_by("-id")[0]
    max_id = latestQuote.id
    quote = Quote.objects.get(pk=randint(1,max_id))
    subprocess.Popen(['notify-send',quote.quote])
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: The command executes Django's manage.py script with a custom command 'crontab' and the manage.py file already has the line you posted and it is also executable by default.

Comment: nop,
Here is the output appears in the syslog
`Nov 22 11:55:01 DEVPC-01 CRON[25401]: (anas) CMD (/usr/bin/python /home/anas/storage/motinder/manage.py crontab run 5ade4dc167538a33802640eeb92219ad #&>/tmp/mycommand.log # django-cronjobs for motinder)`

Comment: You should have an environment variables issue: http://askubuntu.com/questions/23009/reasons-why-crontab-does-not-work.

Comment: Another tip if you are using virtualenv: http://codeinthehole.com/writing/running-django-cronjobs-within-a-virtualenv/

Answer (score 0):

Where is `'notify-send'`? `cron` doesn't run in the same environment as your login shell, and so python may not know where to find it.

You can help yourself by forcing something to happen if the `Popen()` call fails. Currently, nothing will happen, because you are not capturing any output of it.

*(Also, it's generally bad not to wait for your `Popen` calls to finish, unless you have a good reason.)*

There are various utility functions in `subprocess` to help. Try this instead:

```
def notify():
    subprocess.check_call(['notify-send',"TEST"])
```

This will block until the process completes, and raise an exception that will be printed to `stderr` if it fails, e.g. because it can't find `'notify-send'`, which should go to `/var/log/cron` (or possibly `/var/log/syslog` on your system?) and which will let you debug further.